# Find the sum of inverses $\bmod p$ of numbers in range $[1,\frac{p-1}{2}]$

Tags: number-theory, inverse

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Is it possible to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}k^{-1}\bmod p$ more efficiently than in $O(p)$?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a long comment for collecting ideas.
Using Stirling numbers of the second kind
$$\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k^{-1}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k^{p-2}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}\sum_{h=0}^{p-2}{p-2 \brace h}\binom{k}{h}h!\equiv  \sum_{h=0}^{p-2}{p-2 \brace h}\binom{(p+1)/2}{h+1}h!\pmod{p} $$
and there might be a useful [analogue](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa94/aa9413.pdf) of [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) for these Stirling numbers.
Another chance might be to define
$$ P_l \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}k^l\pmod{p} $$
and infer the value of $P_{p-2}$ from $P_0=-\frac{1}{2},P_1=-\frac{1}{2^3},P_2=0,P_3=\frac{1}{2^6},P_4=0,P_5=-\frac{1}{2^7},P_6=0,P_7=\frac{17}{2^{11}}\ldots$
Here of course $\frac{1}{2}$ stands for $2^{-1}\pmod{p}$, i.e. $\frac{p+1}{2}$. [Some strategies](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2010-79-272/S0025-5718-2010-02367-1/S0025-5718-2010-02367-1.pdf) for the evaluation of Bernoulli numbers $\pmod{p}$ involve the Von Staudt-Clausen theorem and the Chinese remainder theorem.